# tcsh creating backup files

Tags: unix, tcsh

I'm trying to write a script that backs up a file which is given as parameter, in a way that  a running number should be added to each copy of the file. For example, if the name of the original file was `aa.c`, then the first backup copy will be called `aa.1.c`. In the next time backup is run, the copy should be called `aa.2.c`, then `aa.3.c`, and so on. In addition ,the script should automatically find the copy with the highest number, and use it to create the new number.

Anyone know how can I do that with `foreach` loop?

Comment: Show (an example of) your code.

Comment: if your backup files (and maybe a lot of them) reside on another location then the originals, this will get excessive search before copy can be done, why not use a timestamp instead of counters. thus you are able to easily delete backup files too old without taking care of individual numbering? make `STAMP="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)` and use like `tar cfz yourfile-$STAMP.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how can I do that with `foreach` loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
foreach file ($*:q)
    @ numb=1
    while (-e $file:r.$numb.$file:e)
        @ numb++
    end
    cp -p $file $file:r.$numb.$file:e
end
```